# How to verify the X509Certificate2 is signed by another X509Certificate2 public key

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, x509certificate, x509

In .NET,I wanted to verify the X509Certificate2 is signed by another X509Certificate2 public key.

To be more precise, I wanted to implement verify method of https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/Certificate.htmlverify. In this we have to pass public key to certificate that has to be verified.

Like this we do in Java:

```java
    java.security.cert.X509Certificate cert
    java.security.cert.X509Certificate intermediate_cert
    cert.verify(intermediate_cert.getPublicKey());
```

**In dot net, I am not sure what is equivalate of verify() method of Java. I want to implement in same manner.**

I have tried build(), Verify(), chain.Build() , but I am not sure, whether it is anywhere near to Java verify() method.

*Please someone guide me. Thanks for help.*

Comment: What is your final goal? What you are trying to accomplish in result?

Comment: I want to verifies that a certificate was signed using the private key of intermediate  certificate public key.